# Max Date in Qlikview Expression

Tags: date, max, qlikview

I have a Qlikview where I have data loaded for various dates. The pivot table in the qlikview shows the change in values from previous day. so for every selected day, I need the previous date to pick values from.

So I have

Dates 31/08/2021, 28/07/2021, 27/07/2021, 25/07/2021

Based on the date selected, i want the previous date. how do i do it in the qlikview expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your field is named `DateField` you could try this:

```
=Max({1<DateField = {"<$(=Min(DateField))"}>} DateField)
```

`"<$(=Min(DateField))"` will search for all dates less than the [minimum] date selected. The `Max` expression will then return the greatest date of this set.